# WordPress OPTIONS are saving the wrong input

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to save WordPress settings in the database. I am using below code to do the thing. The issue is whatever the input I give it only save "p" in the database.

```
    // Display the admin options page
function options_page_fn() {

?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="icon32" id="icon-options-general"><br></div>
        <h2>Settings</h2>
        Here you can update the details of your options.
        <form action="" method="post" name="options">
        <?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
        <?php $opt_api = plugin_options['api_key']; ?>
        <?php $opt_loc = plugin_options['loc_id']; ?>
        <?php $opt_app = plugin_options['app_id']; ?>
        <?php $opt_ulr = plugin_options['url']; ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'options_save', 'options_save_nonce' ); ?>
        <p class="submit">
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
        </p>
        </form>

    </div>
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && ( $opt_api ) ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'options_save_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST[ 'options_save_nonce' ], 'options_save' ) ) {

         $arr = array("api_key"=> $opt_api, "loc_id" => $opt_loc, "app_id" => $opt_app, "url" => $opt_ulr);
        update_option('plugin_options', $arr);
        echo "Updated" . $opt_api;
   }else{
       echo "Update Failed";
   }
}
else {
    echo "No API KEY";
}
}
```

I know I am doing wrong, But I don't know where I am Doing. Help me.

Comment: Are there any hidden fields on the page you are trying to save when you inspect element, that are called by settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?

Comment: No hidden fields, but I think it because of the first letter from the variable `plugin-options`. Apart from this is there any way to verify nonce for the forms which actions is for `options.php`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `plugin_options` a defined constant? It contains no leading `$`, i.e. `$plugin_options`.

Comment: Also, `$munch_opt_api` doesn't appear to be defined at all, so it appears it should always write `No API KEY`.

Comment: the <p class="submit"> seems a little odd should this be a button instead of a paragraph or perhaps it might work as a div instead?